# Explode string at any integer and delete the integer

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace, explode

Example:

```
$string = "Apple0Bannana0Bannana1Cherry0";
```

What I need from said string:

```
Array(
[0] => Apple
[1] => Banana
[2] => Banana
[3] => Cherry
)
```

Something likely using preg_replace and/or explode, but I am not quite sure.

Problem is, there could be any int there between 0 and 49, so I am not sure how to get it to explode dynamically.

Comment: I think by explode you mean "split". If you do some searching for the php split function this may help.

Comment: Unfortunately split has been removed as of PHP 7, but I did look into that a bit as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var_dump( preg_split('~\d+~', preg_replace('~^\d+|\d+$~', '', $string)) );
```

First remove numbers at the start and end of the string, then split by one or more digits.

Thanks @Rizier123 for the hint for improvement:

```
var_dump( preg_split('~\d+~', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) );
```

Comment: Take a look at the fourth parameter of `preg_split()`

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 ! Added your hint.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Quasimodo and Rizier!